# ImageMagick convert produces a darker CMYK PDF than PhotoShop

Tags: pdf, imagemagick, ghostscript, cmyk

The ImageMagick (IM) result of this command

```
convert myRGB.png -colorspace cmyk cmyk.pdf <br>
```

is not as bright or as close to the screen colors as a Photoshop produced CMYK PDF. `myRGB.png` is a PNG file produced using GIMP.

I don't own Photoshop, and would like to stick with open source tools. 
The current Ubuntu release of of IM is 6.7.7. That IM version produces very dark, totally unusable, CMYK PDF.

I built 7.0.2-6 Q16 from source on Ubuntu 14.0.4, after also building LCMS package from source, and the above command works better, but the CMYK PDF as stated above is less bright and less close to the screen colors than the similar Photoshop output. E.g. blacks are not totally black; the sky color is dull blue instead of bright blue/cyan.

I've tried using ICC files downloaded from Adobe as in the following

```
convert myRGB.png -colorspace cmyk -profile WebCoatedSWOP2006Grade5.icc cmyk.pdf
```

I've tried this command with all 14 Adobe ICC files and there is no difference in any of them. Although, I admit I do not understand under what circumstances the ICC comes into play or if it is appropriate to this problem at all.

The simple question is why does IM convert tool not match the Photoshop results for CMYK? 
The second question is, if IM can't be made to do it: is there any open source tool or tools that can match the Photoshop results for producing a CMYK PDF from and RGB PNG?

Answer (score 1):

There are two applications involved, as you presumably know since you tagged this with Ghostscript. You haven't said which version of Ghostscript you have installed but the first thing I would do is remove ImageMagick from the equation.

Find out whether IM is having Ghostscript produce RGB or CMYK output, my bet is that it is getting RGB from GS. You'll need to find out what Ghostscript command line IM is using and I can't tell you how to do that. Assuming that the Ghostscript output is RGB then this would explain why altering the IM settings makes no difference.

Proceeding on the assumption that the above is correct, use the png16m device in Ghostscript to produce RGB PNG files directly, this reduces the scope of the problem:

```
gs -sDEVICE=png16m -o out.png input.pdf
```

Now, you don't say what version of Ghostscript you have installed, but assuming its relatively recent you can look in the /ghostpdl/doc directory and find considerable information on using colour management in Ghostscript, the document GS9_Color_Management.pdf may be helpful. It will certainly give you a myriad of opportunities to alter the output.

Comment: Just FYI, the command you don't know is `identify -list delegate` which will tell you the commands that `IM` uses to *delegate* tasks to external programs such as `ghostscript`.

Comment: Just beat me to it Mark. There is a delegates.xml file in the Imagemagick folder. I do not know if it displays all the information used but you can edit it. I can not remember how to do it now but you can also create your own entry with a different name if you want and call it from Imagemagick.

Comment: That's useful, so if jsmithson can figure out how to configure GS to solve his problem, then he can add the relevant command line parameters there, potentially even creating a new named setup specifically for this purpose ? Sounds useful to me.

Comment: I have had a look on the Imagemagick forum and found this thread +KenS http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=7392&hilit=custom+delegate+decode Not the one I was thinking of but probably better.

Comment: GS version is 9.10. Ken, your gs command is producing a png from a pdf, correct? That's the reverse of what I am doing. Do I run the PDF produced by the subject command as input.pdf? How do I evaluate the result? I didn't find the ghostpdl directory on my machine but I found the CM pdf online. Mark, thank you for the identify command. I think I see that ps and eps can be transformed to a pdf; e.g. ps<=>pdf  "gs' ... " but I don't see a delegate that indicates how a png is transformed to a ps or eps. Unless the blender delegate does it?

Comment: I misunderstood your point then, and I apologise. I presume (but don't know) that IM is producing the PDF itself (no delegate involved), in which case this shouldn't be tagged with Ghostscript I guess. Even if it goes via an intermediate PostScript file, using GS to produce a PDF file, the content will be the image produced by IM. Sorry but I can't help you there.

Comment: No apology necessary. One last try with Ghostscript, if I may. I have tried to use this ghostscript command: gs -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOCACHE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sColorConversionStrategy=CMYK -dProcessColorModel=/DeviceCMYK -sOutputFile=02-gs.pdf 02-rgb.pdf ; The colors are great but the fidelity is greatly reduced by compression (I assume); and the file is still sRGB. Can I turn off compression? Can gs create a CMYK in this manner (as -sColorConversionStrategy implies, to me).

Comment: You will want to read ghostpdl/doc/VectorDevices.htm for the full range of options, you will want to change the ColorImageFilter from DCT to Flate to avoid artefacts caused by quantising JPEG quantised data. Setting ColorConversionStrategy should be sufficient to alter everything to the specified colour model, but you are going to need something newer than 9.10 I should think. Current version is 9.19 with 9.20 due for release in a few weeks. Obviously I'd need to see an example file before I could comment on any problems.